# Как лучше написать sql запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы

1. doctor_clinic_offer (doctor_clinic_offer_id (AI), doctor_id, clinic_id,
   price)
2. doctor_to_clinic (doctor_id, clinic_id)

нужно выводить цены из таблицы врачей в клинике из таблицы doctor_clinic_offer... как написать sql запрос ?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял структуру таблицы и ваш вопрос, то так

```
SELECT `dtc`.*, `dco`.* FROM `doctor_to_clinic` AS `dtc` LEFT JOIN `doctor_clinic_offer` AS `dco` ON `dcf`.`doctor_id` = `dtc`.`doctor_id`
```

Почитайте [LEFT JOIN](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое, но не совсем я ведь знаю $doctor_id ..

Comment: Так что именно вас не устраивает, вам нужно ограничить по id значит еще `where dcf.doctor_id = $id`

Comment: Написал "SELECT dtc.*, dco.* FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "doctor_to_clinic AS dtc LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "doctor_clinic_offer AS dco ON (dco.doctor_id = dtc.doctor_id) WHERE dtc.doctor_id = '" . (int)$doctor_id . "'"  , но предложения  дублируются... а нужно чтобы были предложения конкретного врача...

Comment: Значит у вас несколько записей врачей или клиник, нужно ограничить по `LIMIT 1` или `WHERE` и ваше условие